# K8s Ingress resource does not add original URL prefix to Location response header

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, reverse-proxy, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm unable to specify an `Ingress` resource correctly so that an app's `Location` header is rewritten to include the original URL path in front.

Using config:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-fanout-namespace-xyz
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  namespace: namespace-xyz
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /analytics/spark/master(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: spark-master-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /analytics/jupyter/lab(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: jupyter-proxy-public
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Request URL: https://xx-xx.yyy.elb.amazonaws.com/analytics/jupyter/lab/

Response header: `location: /hub/`

Redirects to https://xx-xx.yyy.elb.amazonaws.com/hub/, 404s.

This should instead send redirect for `location: /analytics/jupyter/lab/`

This seems to be what `add-base-url` was for, which is now deprecated. **What is the proper replacement and how can I effectively make the `Location` become `/analytics/jupyter/lab/hub/` ?**

---

If I remove `rewrite-target` altogether, then http://xx-xx.yyy.elb.amazonaws.com/analytics/jupyter/lab/ does not redirect at all, it just 404s.

---

Info:

NGINX Ingress controller version:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       v1.0.5
  Build:         7ce96cbcf668f94a0d1ee0a674e96002948bff6f
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.19.9

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Kubernetes version (use `kubectl version`):

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21+", GitVersion:"v1.21.2-13+d2965f0db10712", GitCommit:"d2965f0db1071203c6f5bc662c2827c71fc8b20d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-26T01:02:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21+", GitVersion:"v1.21.2-eks-0389ca3", GitCommit:"8a4e27b9d88142bbdd21b997b532eb6d493df6d2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-31T01:34:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Environment:

- AWS EKS
- Amazon Linux 2

ingress-nginx-controller was installed thorugh ArgoCD / Helm with version info shown above and no values overridden.

```sh
$ kubectl describe ingressclasses
Name:         nginx
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-controller
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/version=1.0.5
              helm.sh/chart=ingress-nginx-4.0.9
Annotations:  <none>
Controller:   k8s.io/ingress-nginx
Events:       <none>
```

Comment: I am not sure what jupyter proxy is exactly, but I think you need to set some sort of `base_url` for the workload behind that service. Now it's unaware of the fact it is being served from a sub path, so when it send the redirect it sends as if it was (and actually is) served from root url.

Comment: I see that there is a helm for jupyter which includes [ingress](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/jupyterhub/jupyterhub?modal=template&template=ingress.yaml) and baseUrl can be set in the [values](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/jupyterhub/jupyterhub?modal=values&path=hub.baseUrl).

Comment: A quick test showed that `helm install my-jupyterhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub -n jupyterhub --create-namespace --set hub.baseUrl="/analytics/jupyter/lab" --set ingress.enabled=true --set ingress.pathType="ImplementationSpecific" --set proxy.service.type=NodePort --set ingress.annotations.'kubernetes\.io/ingress\.class'=nginx` deployed `jupyter hub` for me with `Ingress` and I was able to access it via `<ip_address>/analytics/jupyter/lab/ `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jupyter-proxy` needs its base_url to be set for the workload behind that service. Now it's unaware of the fact it is being served from a sub path, so when it send the redirect it sends as if it was (and actually is) served from the root url.

A quick test showed that

```sh
helm install my-jupyterhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub -n jupyterhub \
--create-namespace \
--set hub.baseUrl="/analytics/jupyter/lab" \
--set ingress.enabled=true \
--set ingress.pathType="ImplementationSpecific" \
--set proxy.service.type=NodePort \
--set ingress.annotations.'kubernetes\.io/ingress\.class'=nginx
```

deployed `jupyter hub` for me with `Ingress` and I was able to access it via `<X.X.X.X>/analytics/jupyter/lab/`

Comment: [reposting from above] This works, but doesn't feel quite right from a design perspective. Instead of telling the application layer about a baseUrl, I want the reverse proxy (Nginx) itself to rewrite the Location header that it gets back from the app (Jupyter). That means Jupyter never needs to know about its baseUrl directly.

Comment: I think (I am guessing here) the problem with this approach (of making nginx rewrite responses) is with the fact that it is not just the Location Header which is to be rewritten, but also the links within html/js.

Comment: Yes, that is true - I've seen that issue as well with, for example, the Spark master UI using something like `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/spark-logo-77x50px-hd.png"` when that href needs to be `href="/analytics/spark/master/static/spark-logo-77x50px-hd.png"`. Feel like Ingress must just be not clicking for me and that I am missing something obvious, since not every Helm chart provides the equivalent of a baseUrl (Spark does not).

Comment: Internet says that spark is just not ready to be ran from behind the reverse proxy. There was a PR that never was merged and an [article](https://8vi.cat/configure-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-sparkui/), where they show how this is possible with `sub_filter` which (by the way) does exactly what we were discussing - rewriting the content that is sent back.

Comment: Eek, okay. Thanks for digging that up.